# Good way to compare huge strings in Python?

Tags: python, string, compare, beautifulsoup, match

I built/expanded upon a Python web crawler that goes through a site and builds a dictionary to store what it finds (here's the template I used if anybody's interested, it's quite good: http://berrytutorials.blogspot.ca/2010/03/simple-web-crawler-in-python-using.html). There's a bit more to the dictionary than this, but for the purposes of this question a single item is essentially of the form `{page_url : html}`, where html is the entire html of the page in the form of a string.

The crawler is built to not index the same page twice, but a potential problem that could easily arise as pointed out by the template's author is identical pages being recognized by the crawler as different because the url parameters are different. For example, www.example.com/path?param=1 and www.example.com/path?param=2 would both get added to the dictionary since the urls are technically different, even though the content of each page is probably identical, or nearly identical. The only way I can think of to fix this is to compare the massive html strings stored in the dictionary with one another after the scrape is complete and see if there are any matches - basically just

```
    if html_str_1 == html_str_2:
        # eliminate one of them
```

for every possible pair. But obviously this would be very resource- and time-consuming.

Does anybody know a better way to accomplish this? I'd also like to be able to detect nearly identical html that maybe differs only by a few trivial characters. I'm new to Python, so I'm not all that familiar with the various libraries out there. Maybe BeautifulSoup could do something like this?

(Note: I know for the example that I gave I could just parse out any parameters from the urls before analyzing them, but that's only one possible cause of duplicate html and I want to cover everything. Also, different parameters might result in vastly different pages in some cases.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hashing is the way to go. I'd go with MD5 since it's fast-- it's a disadvantage for cryptographic purposes, but using an expensive hash (like SHA512) for indexing is just a waste of your cycles.

Since web pages often contain links that are based on their own request options (as in your example), and perhaps a time stamp showing when it was fetched, you'll need to clean up/ normalize the fetched pages before you hash them. Remove whatever you think can vary between identical pages, hash the result, and use it as the dictionary key. That way you can check if a new page has known hash in nominally O(1) time-- courtesy of python's dict management.

Comment: Alright, you've convinced me to go with hashing, but how would I normalize the pages? How could I determine what would likely be trivial variances between otherwise identical pages?

Comment: If you are interest in the content of the pages, I think you should strip all the tags and the spaces from your text. If the interesting part is not in the header/footer strip them as well. Then you'll do hashing indexing. This way you should remove at least some trivial differences.

Comment: It really depends on why you're collecting the pages. Stripping the tags and page decorations, as @furins suggests, is _probably_ a good idea-- it could catch duplicates when the same text appears on different websites, for example. For the scenario you mentioned (similar URLs that end up fetching the same page), I might strip URLs that include the URL of the page itself; or strip the GET options; etc. But the specifics _really_ depend on what you're up to.

Answer (score 2):

Create a [hash](http://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html) of the HTML and compare those. I would recommend `hashlib.sha512()`.

```
In [1]: from hashlib import sha512

In [2]: html = '<p>This is a test</p>'

In [3]: sha512(html).digest()
Out[3]: '\xb4\xda\xc2\xcb\x16\xd3\\\xa1F\x8a\\\xe5-z\xc6\xd1\xf95\x0f\x13\xf6k\xb4\xfd\xb9I\xde\xf0\x8dQ\xff\xdb\x9d\xa2\x0f\x1b\x8al\xfe\xac\xce\xe4n*\xd3\xd8M\xf3E\x05\xc6\xc9\xeejV8\xf8\x9a:\x86|q\x1f\x1c'
```

You should change your dictionary to store the hash as well;

```
{page_url : (hash, html)}
```

**Edit:** Hashing is quite fast. I created a 10MB file of random data:

```
dd if=/dev/random of=random.dat bs=1M count=10
```

Read and hashed it:

```
In [6]: with open('random.dat') as infile:
    data = infile.read()
   ...:     

In [7]: %timeit sha512(data).digest()
10 loops, best of 3: 61.5 ms per loop
```

So you can hash 10MB in around 60 ms.

An MD5 hash is twice as fast;

```
In [4]: %timeit md5(data).digest()
10 loops, best of 3: 24.1 ms per loop
```

The chance of a collision (two different text producing the same hash value) is somewhat greater, though.

Comment: I did think over the hashing approach, but isn;t it as resource intensive (or may be even more) as entire content matching?

Comment: No, because you only have to do it _once_. Comparisons have to be done for _all_ possibilities.

Comment: I did this on ten thousands documents retrieved by ocr, several of them were >10 mb plain text and was not so intensive. You may use md5 if you want to save cpu cycles, and eventually use a sorted array

Answer (score 2):

Use something like md5 to hash the HTML, then use two dictionaries: one mapping URL to content-hash, and another mapping content hash to actual content.  For example, instead of:

```
dict1[ url ] = html
```

Use:

```
import md5

h = md5.new()
h.update(html)
k = h.hexdigest()
dict1[ url ] = k
dict2[ k ] = html
```

That way, identical pages will only be stored once.

Answer (score 1):

> Does anybody know a better way to accomplish this?

An ideal way would be to first

- compare the size of the content
- followed by a random subset of characters
- followed by the entire content

> I'd also like to be able to detect nearly identical html that maybe
>   differs only by a few trivial characters.

Python's library difflib has support for this, but its resource intensive.

Comment: How's the size of the content going to do **anything** if you fetched almost the same page with different flags?

Comment: Thanks, I really like this idea. I might be able to use the size comparison to find very-nearly-identical html as well, by allowing for a range rather than an exact match. I'll look into difflib as well.

Comment: You'll still need to make a completely impractical number of comparisons. Sorry but this approach is a non-starter.

Comment: True it would be a high number of comparisons, but wouldn't comparing sizes be a lot less strenuous than the actual strings?

Comment: @Tyler Two documents of equal size aren't necessarily the same. You'd have to do the compare anyway.